# while adding video with sencha give error Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/css

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I am trying to add sample using sencha i am getting this error **Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/css**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Newpage', {
    extend: 'Ext.Video',
    xtype: 'newpage',
    id:'Newpage',
    config: {
        layout: { type: 'vbox', pack: 'center' },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'video',
                url: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Lzh1kY-L3U',
                width: '320',
                height: '70',
                loop:true,
                posterUrl: 'resources/icons/iTunesArtwork.png'
            }
        ] 
    }
});
```

my code is here don't know where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.Video` is not a container, so you can't have items. The definition should look like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Newpage', {
    extend: 'Ext.Video',
    xtype: 'newpage',
    id:'Newpage',
    config: {
        url: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Lzh1kY-L3U',
        width: '320',
        height: '70',
        loop:true,
        posterUrl: 'resources/icons/iTunesArtwork.png'
    }
});
```

Also, the video tag is just a wrapper around a HTML5 `<video>` tag, you can't just stick a youtube URL in there and expect it to work.

Comment: Updated answer, you can't do that.